# No matching constructor for initialization in a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, c++14

I started writing this class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 16
#define EMPTY_SIZE 0

template<class KeyT,class ValueT>
class HashMap
{
 public:
  HashMap ();
  HashMap(const std::vector<KeyT> &keys, const std::vector<KeyT> &values);

 private:
  std::vector<std::pair<KeyT,ValueT>> *_table;
  int _capacity;
  int _size;

};

template<class KeyT,class ValueT>
HashMap<KeyT,ValueT>::HashMap () :
    _table (new std::vector<std::pair<KeyT,ValueT>> [DEFAULT_CAPACITY]),
    _capacity(DEFAULT_CAPACITY),
    _size(EMPTY_SIZE){}

template<class KeyT,class ValueT>
HashMap<KeyT,ValueT>::HashMap (const std::vector<KeyT> &keys,
                               const std::vector<KeyT> &values)
{
  if (keys.size() != values.size())
  {
    throw (std::length_error(""));
  }
  _table = new std::vector<std::pair<KeyT,ValueT>> [DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
  _capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
  _size = EMPTY_SIZE;
  for (int i = 0; i <(int)keys.size() ; ++i)
  {
    //TODO:add insert here
  }
}
```

and im trying to create a new object using the second constructor like this

```
HashMap<std::string, float> hash_m ({"a", "b", "c"}, {1.0f, -0.34f, 11.f});
```

but I get this error "No matching constructor for initialization of 'HashMap<std::string, float>' (aka 'HashMap<basic_string, float>')"
I don't understand why it doesn't recognize the constructor?

Comment: The type of the 2nd parameter to the constructor is wrong. Keep re-reading "`const std::vector<KeyT> &values`" until you see the problem. VTC as a typo. Additionally, the template also suffers from a major problem called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". Nothing useful is accomplished by making `_table` a pointer. The only end result is that the resulting class is no longer rule-of-3 compliant, making it very easy to create memory corruption and hard to debug crashes. You will save yourself major headaches if it's just a `std::vector<std::pair<KeyT,ValueT>> _table`;

Comment: thanks for the replay this code is a part of my university assignment i have only showed a small part of the class to show the problem, I completely missed the typo thank you

Comment: I'm fairly certain that no matter what else is in this class, it would be extremely difficult for it to have a valid reason to have this pointless use of pointerx. Even if these vectors have to be swapped between different instances of the template: move semantics in modern C++ turn it into a nothing-burger, without opening up a Pandora's nest of memory leaks, memory errors, and other typical problems that are caused by Pointless Use Of Pointers. Plain pointers, like that, are rarely needed any more, in modern C++.

Comment: There's little sense in having a hashmap constructor that accepts vectors. (In the real world, as opposed to university projects).

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but the assignment is to implement a hash table in a specific way,  the table should be dynamically managed, I'm only allowed to use vectors for the buckets, thanks for the help

Comment: But a std::vector does the management for you, it doesn't have to be dynamically stored itself. Internally it's not much more than a pointer to a managed block of memory. Also, are you required to have a constructor signature like this? You can still have a constructor accept something like a std::initializer_list of key-value pairs. That ensures a value for every key, which is a problem with the current version.

Comment: `new std::vector<...>(...)` is *almost always* an error. Your case is no exception.